# Reference a label inside a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi So here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        label1 = tk.Label(container, text="label")
        label1.pack()

app = Window()

print (app.label1.text)

app.mainloop()
```

I am simply trying to retrieve the text from the label widget and print it.
When I run this code I get this error message:

> AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'label1'

I am pretty new to Tkinter but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the `self.` prefix to the label name. `self.label1`. Currently your label is just a local variable to `__init__`. local variables cannot be accessed from anything outside of the function/method. You need to define the label as a class attribute so that it can be accessed from outside of the function/method. Also note that `app.label1.text` is incorrect. You will want to use `app.label1['text']` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your label is not defined as a class attribute. To do this add the `self.` prefix.

Currently your label is just a local variable to `__init__`. Local variables cannot be accessed from anything outside of the function/method. You need to define the label as a class attribute so that it can be accessed from outside of the function/method.

Change this:

```
label1 = tk.Label(container, text="label")
label1.pack()
```

To this:

```
self.label1 = tk.Label(container, text="label")
self.label1.pack()
```

You will also need to change `app.label1.text` to `app.label1['text']` to get your print statement to work.